# Prestashop : Decorate a module's service from another module

Tags: symfony, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to use the module ps_facebook to send a catalog to Facebook but I need to change the name of the product sent.

I already sought and I found that's the module ps_eventbus that manages to load and decorate datas.
Unfortunately there is no hook. My only possibility is to rewrite a part of this service.
This service is loaded by the module ps_eventbus in the file decorate.yml and I want to change the call of this service by our specific service in our module.

So I wonder if it's possible to override properly the service PrestaShop\Module\PsEventbus\Decorator\ProductDecorator and how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the Symfony documentation, here
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/service_decoration.html

As it is not directly related to the PrestaShop itself. If this service is public, you can probably decorate it, as shown in the docs.

Comment: Ok, thank you @Krystian Podemski, I will check.